# React Native: Why so many AndroidManifest.xml files in my project?

Tags: android, react-native

In my react native project. Inside the `android` directory. There so many different `AndroidManifest.xml` files:

```
./app/build/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/out/AndroidManifest.xml
./app/build/intermediates/merged_manifest/release/out/AndroidManifest.xml
./app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
./app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml
./app/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
./app/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml
./app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
./app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Why so many files? How do many different files get generated? What is the purpose of each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge). Below an extract of the docs:

> Your APK file can contain just one AndroidManifest.xml file, but your
> Android Studio project may contain several—provided by the main source
> set, build variants, and imported libraries. So when building your
> app, the Gradle build merges all manifest files into a single manifest
> file that's packaged into your APK.
>
> The manifest merger tool combines all XML elements from each file by
> following some merge heuristics and by obeying merge preferences that
> you have defined with special XML attributes. This page describes how
> manifest merging works and how you can apply merge preferences to
> resolve merge conflicts.